# Can the Y-combinator really terminate?

Tags: lambda-calculus

My understanding of the Y-combinator is that it never terminates (`Yg = g(Yg)`). Its termination is only decided **externally** to the $\lambda$ specification when it has reached a fixed point (`g(x)=x`) because based on its $\lambda$ expression there is no exit from the infinite loop even when the fixed point is reached.

Am I wrong?

Comment: What reduction strategy are you considering? Call by value or call by name?

Comment: I'm not sure how termination is decided by the reduction strategy. Call-by-value (eager) evaluation will undoubtedly be non-terminating compared to call-by-name or call-by-need (lazy) evaluations which can often handle infinite structures (like `take 10 [1..]`) by discarding un-evaluated sub-expressions. Still, termination in those latter cases can only occur when the reduction strategy decides to discard i.e stop further recursion by identifying the fixed point. This is happening externally to the bare lambda formalism. Doesn't it?

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood that lambda's beta reduction does not itself define an order of precedence when an expression contains multiple applications. A lambda formalism thus requires a reduction strategy to specify this precedence.

Comment: Termination can occur with lazy evaluation because of how branching is formulated (e.g. $\lambda x.\lambda y.y$). The infinite sub-expression is discarded when the terminal branch is reached leaving just the normal expression.

Comment: The Y-combinator would not terminate however for eager inner evaluation strategies like the Applicative Order strategy.

Comment: Exactly. For eager evaluation, you need the Z combinators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Strict_fixed-point_combinator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terms containing the Y combinator can be *weakly normalizing*: they can terminate for a certain order of evaluation, i.e. for a certain evaluation strategy. No term containing the Y combinator applied to another term can be *strongly normalizing*, i.e. no term containing Y applied to another term terminates for all evaluation strategies, since the infinite reduction chain $Y \, M \to_\beta^* M \, (Y \, M) \to_\beta^* M \, (M \, (Y \, M)) \to_\beta^* \ldots$ is possible.

There are terms $M$ such that $Y \, M$ has no normal form, i.e. such that there is no reduction strategy that reduces $Y \, M$ to a value. For example $Y (\lambda x. x) \to_\beta^* (\lambda x.x) (Y (\lambda x.x)) \to_\beta Y (\lambda x. x)$ is a recursive functions that just spins (`let x = x`). (The lack of another reduction chain that terminates is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Under call-by-value (only ever reducing $M \, N$ when $M$ and $N$ are values), $Y \, M$ only converges if $M$ does not use its argument, i.e. if $Y \, M$ is not “really” recursive. Under call-by-name (always reducing the outermost redex first), $Y \, M$ converges if the recursive function that it defines terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was curious about all the $Y$-combinator-related questions, so I decided to put up my old (optimal) combinator evaluator [Combo](https://github.com/RockBrentwood/Combo).

I'll use this as a reference implementation for the question on hand and make brief mention of the alternatives.

Here's where I get. The relevant expression is $Y = W S (C B D)$, where:
$$
W = λxλy(x y y),\quad S = λxλyλz(x z (y z)),\\
C = λxλyλz(x z y),\quad B = λxλyλz(x (y z)),
$$
as usual, which "Combo" accepts as primitive combinators, and also
$$D = λx(x x),$$
which "Combo" also treats as a primitive combinator.

If you define $Y$ and run it, by feeding "Combo" the expression
$$Y = W\ S\ (C\ B\ D), Y$$
it will terminate with $S (C B D) (C B D)$, which it writes as $\_0 = C B D, S \_0 \_0$ (because "Combo" never writes the same subexpression twice, in any expression, except for names).

If you run it with the η-rule (using the "-e" command-line option), it will complain that the reduction is non-terminating. Its implementation of the η-rule is equivalent to running $Y$ on a dummy argument, say $f$, with the η-rule on $Y f$, if necessary, and then abstracting out the $f$ after it finishes ... except it will never finish, because $Y f$ evaluates to $f (Y f)$. So, it blocks the reduction.

In and of itself, $Y f$ does not terminate.

On the other hand, if $f$ is defined as some other combinator expression, then it may terminate. For instance, if you run "Combo" on
$$Y = W\ S\ (C\ B\ D),\ Y\ (K\ x),$$
where $K = λxλy x$ then it will produce $x$ as a result. Not all combinator reduction strategies will terminate on $Y$ combinator expressions - not even on this. Some may try to expand $Y (K x)$ into $K x (Y (K x))$ and then keep expanding the $Y (K x)$ sub-terms, without bothering to chop it off with the $K$. Since "Combo" is optimal, it will chop off the subterm.

As an aside, "Combo" accepts (and pre-compiles) lambda expressions. So, you can also define $Y = λf((λx f (x x))(λx f (x x)))$, and run $Y$, by giving "Combo" the expression
$$Y = \setminus f(g = \setminus x\ f\ (x\ x),\ g\ g), Y.$$
It will yield the same result as $W S (C B D)$ - as listed above.

You can see the progress of evaluation with the "-s" command-line option; but note that it only shows the evaluation of the subexpression it is working on, at each step, not of the whole expression, and an expression like $C C C C C C ...$ will reduce in one step to $C C C$, independent of the number of $C$'s beyond the first three (because it never evaluates any sub-expression more than once).